# Add List box to List<ListBox> to pass to foreach loop ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Hi I'm trying to create a list of ListBox's in ASP.NET so that I can then iterate it to test if it has been selected.

```
    List<string> con = new List<string>();
    List<ListBox> lb = new List<ListBox>();
    foreach (Control c in _pH_Outer_MainCri.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ListBox)
        {
            con.Add(c.ID.ToString());
            lb.Add(c.??);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting caught up on that last part.  Basically then I can

```
foreach(ListBox a in lb)
    {
        if(a.TestSelection() == true )
        {
            BuildQuery(a);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help ...

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Are you getting an error or is it not behaving as expected? What were you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid placing the controls in a list by using LINQ, like this:

```
var listboxen =
    from control in _pH_Outer_MainCri.Controls
    where control is ListBox
    select control as ListBox;
```

You can then foreach through the list boxes without having to build an intermediate collection.

Comment: I love linq its like the swiss army knife of C#.  I like this I thnk it is very elegant, however I can't seem t get it to work "Error 2 Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection'.  'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'control"

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding all listboxes then you would want

```
lb.Add((ListBox)c);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I get overwhelmed, I often find it helpful to take a step back and think about my structures:

`List<ListBox> lb` - This is a list and each member in the list is of a type `ListBox`.

In your loop, you want to pull out all of the listboxes, so when you have:
`if (c is ListBox)
        {` you know that `c` is already of the type listbox, which is the same type `lb` is storing.  It is simply a matter of adding `c` to your collection in `lb` with `lb.Add(c);`

Separately - do you really need to store these items only to loop through them again and call `BuildQuery`?  Looping through, putting them in a list, and then looping through that collection again may be extra overhead depending on what you are doing.

Comment: This is very true, I've spent so much time building the layout of the controls that I think I need to step back a little.  I'm in design mode not functionality mode lol ...